# Limit strings in text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to limit the characters in a block, and I've managed to do it like this (I've followed [this solution](http://prntscr.com/5p927y))

```
      $(".nome-produto").text($(this).text().substr(0, 70)+'...');
```

It's working as needed, but the problem is I have multiple items, and the text is being copied...

The printscreen is [here](http://prntscr.com/5p927y)

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [function](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) that will return correct text for every node in the matching set.

```
$(function(){
   $('.nome-produto').text(function(_, text){
       return text.substr(0, 70) + '...';
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a class selector so I believe the jquery statement you are using would be applied to all items of that class.   You could either have a statement for each item (not desirable) or you should be able to do something like:

```
$(".nome-produto").each( function() {
   $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 70)+'...');
});
```